# How to change div height and animate scroll position simultaneously in jQuery

Tags: jquery, position, jquery-animate, height, scrolltop

I'm trying  to show a div with a map in it (previously set to display:none and a set height) by both animating the height and moving the page so the div is fully visible.
This works but it happens in two steps - I want it simultaneous.
(The commented out line was an attempt that doesn't work).

Any ideas?

```
$( "#map" ).animate({
    height:"show"
    //scrollTop: $(this).get(0).scrollHeight
    },400,"swing", function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#map")[0].scrollHeight },400);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the second animate call is not required. You've wrapped it in a function that is executed on completion of the first animation. It will never run concurrently in that manner.

Try the following code:

```
$( "#map" )
        .animate(
        {   height:"show",
            scrollTop: 400
        },400,"swing");
    });
```

I ran this code in a local environment and the content of my map div scrolled to the location specified at the same time the height expanded.

Good Luck!

Comment: No, sadly that doesn't do anything for me.. 
But to clarify it's the page I want to scoll, not the div on top of everything else.

I knew why they weren't synchronous but of course it looks clunky in two steps.
Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Seem to have it fixed - this works synchronously:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 300 }, 3000);
$( "#map" ).animate({
    height:"show"
    },3000,"swing", function(){
    do more stuff for Google map
});
```